# CSS select parent and all descendants

Tags: css

```css
.parent div
```

selects all `div`s that are descendants of `.parent`, is there a way to include `.parent` in the selection too without doing

```css
.parent, .parent div
```

something less verbose?

Comment: doesn't seem so verbose to me:)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the [all shorthand property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/all) instead but I think your provided example is totally fine.

```css
.parent {
   color: red;
   ...
}

.parent > div {
  all: inherit;
}
```

Keep in mind **this overrides the default value for all properties**.

The `>` in `.parent > div` selects all `div` elements that are the immediate child of a `.parent` element.

If this isn't what you're trying to achieve i'd just stick to your original.